# Unit Test Web Forms on IIS and accessing controls on page Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, iis-7, webforms

I'm trying to unit test code behind methods that have logic in them and access controls on the page.  I've looked through many examples, for instance http://kmanojt.blogspot.com/2010/09/unit-testing-aspx-and-acsx-pages-with.html or http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/01/aspnet_unit_testing_on_iis.html.

If I add HostType then I can no longer debug anything.  If I remove HostType and leave just UrlToTest I can debug, but testContextInstance.RequestedPage is always null.  Because the page is null I can't access any controls on the page and when it invokes Method1 it throws an exception because the textbox control it is trying to access is null.  I'm using IIS 7 so am not using AspNetDevelopmentServerHost setting.

Example code:

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Web;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass()]

public class TestClass 
{

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;

public TestContext TestContext {
    get { return testContextInstance; }
    set { testContextInstance = value; }
}

[TestMethod(), HostType("ASP.NET"), UrlToTest("https://localhost/xxx/Home.aspx")]
public void TestMethod()
{
    System.Web.UI.Page page = testContextInstance.RequestedPage;

    PrivateObject po = new PrivateObject(page);

    po.Invoke("Method1");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to W3WP.exe or do a Debugger.Break(). Sometimes you may need to debug in different Visual Studio instance. See the below link.
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1246417.aspx?How+to+Debug+unit+tests+for+ASP+NET+web+application](http://forums.asp.net/t/1246417.aspx?How%20to%20Debug%20unit%20tests%20for%20ASP%20NET%20web%20application)